# Cakephp sql decimal input form

Tags: sql-server, cakephp, decimal, cakephp-2.6

I use cakephp 2.6.4. and sql srv 2012.
I need to save decimal number in format decimal(4,2) -> 4 digits before , and 2 after separator.

In sql server i have data type decimal(4,2) and in model i have validation 'rule' => array('decimal',2).

When i try to save for example 4213,12 it reports message need to round number to 4213 or 4214
I tryed with dot (.) as delimiter, but not works

When i set data type in sql srv float, then i can save, but does not work with decimal,

Any help please?
Tnx

- next i tryed with numeric(4,2) in sql srv, but same thing as with decimal(4,2)
- my validate array is: 'coordinate_x' => array(
          'numeric' => array(
              'rule' => array('decimal',2),

-and everything alse is commented

- i managed to get SQL error: Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Error converting data type varchar to numeric. i removed validate rules for that field. it seems that dacimal value in cakephp equals character. but when i roll back validation rules, than i get error to round a number for example from 1234,12 to 1234 or 1235

Comment: What is the SQL INSERT/UPDATE that is being generated by Cake?

Comment: i dont get any sql.  by pressing submit i get red border around input field with massage. no sql is executed i think. and i think these massage is browsers massage and is connected with database data type. is it possible?

Comment: It sounds like the data is failing on validation and therefore CakePHP is not attempting to update the database. Could you update your question with your model's `$validate` array?

Comment: See https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-tools/blob/2.x/Model/Behavior/NumberFormatBehavior.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resolwed with HTML requirement:

```
<input type="number" step="0.01">
```

Answer (score 1):

`$this->Number->format();` can be used to change the format of the number.

**Example:**

```
$this->Number->format(floor($session->read('max_price')), 
      array('escape' => false, 
            'places' => 0, 
             'thousands' => ','
      ));
```

Place attribute is used to set the decimal value .

Comment: that can i set in controllers beforeSave, i guess?

Comment: No is not work in controller,Its works only view file

Comment: but in view i have only a row for that field:                   echo $this->Form->input('coordinate_x', array('label' => 'Koordinata X', 'title' => 'x u htrs'));

Comment: Can use with help of Java script to  change the format number while u have typing in text box wait i post the link

Comment: http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/  use link to change format of number while u have typing in the input box

Comment: but why to change a format if i am inputing corect format. decimal(4,2) is format number for input is 1234,12 .